# Saving .so file with IDA

Tags: ida, android, arm, apk

I edited a ".so" file (which extracted from an APK) with IDA Pro, and now I am trying to save it with the same format. But it seems that I cannot find it.

Could you please explain to me step by step how to save/export .so format with IDA.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Its the same for everything you edit in IDA:

Patch the .so opcodes (assuming its ELF ARM?) via hex view

Once happy with the patches, go to

Edit --> Patch Program --> Apply patches to input file (Select create backup just in case).

Make sure Start EA and End EA are correct.

Click OK

Repack your APK to include the new .so file.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. The problem is that I am not modifying the Hex. I am trying to modify and rename some paths: ( eg. Java_com_companyname_appname...). I am able to rename them but there are no hex code changes, so when I try to apply patches, I see 0 patches, and no changes to the input file?

Comment: eh.. renaming the string (x)ref is not a modification. you need to modify the string itself.